# Userform button not working when typing in a textbox vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform where you have to enter data into textboxes and then press a button to put the data into the sheet. When I'm typing into the last textbox and I'm done, I click the button and it doesn't respond. Also, I have noticed that my cursor keeps blinking inside the last textbox so I guess there's a problem there (while focused not able to click a button)?

In total I have 4 textboxes, 3 of them use data validation after their value has been updated. The last one does not have data validation.

The weird thing is that, next to the "next button", I have a button to clear the fields and that one works just fine. Below an image from my userform with a little bit of explanation because it's in another language (Dutch). Can anyone help me? Thanks!

[image]

The code used for the "next" button is:

> Note: the data gets validated not only when they updated the value of the textbox, but also an extra time when they click the next button.

```
Private Sub AddNextBtn_Click()
    AddValueMod.AddDisplayOverview
End Sub

Sub AddDisplayOverview() 'This sub is in the "AddValueMod" module
    'Check if information is valid via a function
    If AddInformationValid("AccountSelector", True) And AddInformationValid("Date", True) And AddInformationValid("Amount", True) And AddInformationValid("Description", True) Then
        'If valid, retrieve entered values
        Dim account, dDate, amount, description As String
        account = main.AddAccountSelector.Value
        dDate = main.AddDateInput.Value
        amount = main.AddValue.Value
        description = main.AddDescription.Value
        'Ask for sheet-writing-confirmation
        overview = MsgBox("Kloppen volgende gegevens (kijk goed na!)?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Rekening: " & account & vbCrLf & "Datum: " & dDate & vbCrLf & "Bedrag: " & amount & vbCrLf & "Beschrijving: " & description & vbCrLf & "Vermeerdering/vermindering: Waarde wordt vermeerderd", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Kloppen volgende gegevens?")
        If overview = vbYes Then
            'Write data to sheet
            AddValueMod.AddEnterDataIntoSheet
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

And for the "clear fields" button:

```
Private Sub AddClearFieldsBtn_Click()
    AddValueMod.AddClearFields (True)
End Sub

Sub AddClearFields(askForConfirmation As Boolean) 'This sub is in the "AddValueMod" module
    grey = RGB(128, 128, 128)
    'If askForConfirmation = True, ask for confirmation before clearing fields
    If askForConfirmation = True Then
        confirmationMessage = MsgBox("Bent u zeker dat u de velden wilt leegmaken?" + vbCrLf + "U zal terug opnieuw moeten beginnen.", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Velden leegmaken?")
        If confirmationMessage = vbYes Then
            'Clear fields
            main.AddAccountSelector.Value = ""
            main.AddDateInput.Value = ""
            main.AddValue.Value = ""
            main.AddDescription.Value = ""
        End If
    ElseIf askForConfirmation = False Then
        'Clear fields
        main.AddAccountSelector.Value = ""
        main.AddDateInput.Value = ""
        main.AddValue.Value = ""
        main.AddDescription.Value = ""
    End If
    'Reset the textboxes' borders (they change if an input error occurred)
    main.AddAccountSelectorError.Visible = False
    main.AddAccountSelector.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
    main.AddAccountSelector.BorderColor = grey
    main.AddDateInputError.Visible = False
    main.AddDateInput.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
    main.AddDateInput.BorderColor = grey
    main.AddValueError.Visible = False
    main.AddValue.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
    main.AddValue.BorderColor = grey
    main.AddDescriptionError.Visible = False
    main.AddDescription.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
    main.AddDescription.BorderColor = grey
End Sub
```

P.S.: I've already tried a possible solution with `IsCancel = True/False` that I found online in [this article](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/user-form-cancel-button-not-working-when-focus-in-a-textbox-that-fails-validation.1099949/). It's possible it didn't work because the article is not quite related to my problem but I felt like I should mention it :).

Comment: Please show the code you run by the buttons.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, updated it! Sorry for the incovience.

Comment: You did not provide the `AddValueMod.AddEnterDataIntoSheet` sub so I can not trace the code. I just comment: The variables `account, dDate, amount, description As String` are ofcourse valid only locally in `AddDisplayOverview`. But I guess you do read the values again from the form in AddEnterDataIntoSheet? Are you using `Option Explicit` in your code modules? If not, please do. Anyway, put a breakpoint on the one line in `AddNextBtn_Click()` then step into the other subs with the debugger and pay attention to how the variables end up in the sheet. Or where something unexpected happens.

Comment: Also, if any data is deemed invalid by `AddInformationValid()` you are not showing the fact to the user! **You are just silently bypassing the data reading and the `AddEnterDataIntoSheet` sub**. Looks like the validation procedure could be the culprit.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in `AddNextBtnClick()` and traced the execution with the debugger?

Comment: You were right! I indeed messed up something with the AddInformationValid() function. For one field, the function always returns False and never True. Thanks for your help with troubleshooting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide all relevant code. `AddInformationValid()` and `AddEnterDataIntoSheet` are missing.

However, if the `AddInformationValid()` returns `False` on any item, the behaviour is just as you describe. In `AddDisplayOverview()` there will be no error message, the `AddEnterDataIntoSheet` sub will be bypassed and on return from the button handler the cursor remains flashing in the last entry field.

You need to verify and correct the `AddInformationValid()` Function.

I also strongly recommend to show an error message if the data validation fails.

Comment: You were right! I indeed messed up something with the `AddInformationValid()` function. For one field, the function always returns `False` and never `True`. Thanks for your help with troubleshooting!